# what is the difference between tidy functions parseString(),repairString(),cleanRepair()

Tags: php, tidy

I have just begun using tidy but i am confused by its functions `parseString()`, `repairString()`, `cleanRepair()`. i have gone through the php.net manual and other sites but can get it? the php manual says that `parseString()` parses the document stored in a string and `repairString()` repairs the document stored in a string. But what is the difference between parsing and repairing. the both accept optional parameters and they can be given the same parameters so what is the difference? when to use which function and when both? i have seen in a tutorial,it used both the functions. can somebody help? also point to any useful links if you know. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`parseString` takes in a string, and creates a new `tidy` instance. `cleanRepair` cleans and repairs the contents of that `tidy` instance.  You can then get the tidied HTML by converting the `tidy` instance, e.g. by `echo`ing it.

`repairString` basically does all this in one go.  This combination of actions is the most common option, so this is a shortcut method.  Notice that it returns a string, whereas `parseString` returns the new `tidy` instance and `cleanRepair` returns a boolean to show whether the operation was successful.

---

So these are (approximately) equivalent:

```
$tidy = new Tidy;
$tidy->parseString($yourHTML);
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;

$tidy = new Tidy;
echo $tidy->repairString($yourHTML);
```

Comment: thanks.But still i do not get the difference between parsing and cleaning?

Comment: @lovesh Before `tidy` can do its magic on a string, it has to parse it -- scan through and see what's going on, and store this in an internal representation. You can then clean it -- though there are other operations you can do. And yes, you should be able to use `repairString()` as I have in my second example.

Comment: can u help me with this [](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168558/unable-to-scrape-content-from-a-website)